# How to view all autocomplete options?

Tags: python, scripting

I wanted to view all the stuff inside bpy.types so I used the autocomplete inside the python console. However the results are cut off. How can I get the full list? I'm trying to find a method so I can call a function as soon as anything is imported.

[image]

*Where the autocomplete list starts*

Comment: In answer to title  `dir(bpy.types)` produces a list of strings _eg_ "VIEW3D_PT_overlay"  the class being `cls = getattr(bpy.types, "VIEW3D_PT_overlay")`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found an alternative situation. I wanted to make a dropdown menu that added all armature objects in the loaded file. My idea was for it to update every time an object is imported. I was able to achieve this based on dynamic list examples of this website:

https://elfnor.com/drop-down-and-button-select-menus-for-blender-operator-add-ons.html#dynamic-lists

Comment: Worth reading: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57306/31447), [Search enum list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44886/search-enum-list/45069#45069), [What ui would work for choosing from a long, long list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/what-ui-would-work-for-choosing-from-a-long-long-list), [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30444/31447) and there is probably a lot more...

Comment: Using `dir(bpy.types)` to find panel classes.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163360/is-it-possible-to-change-the-active-bl-category-with-python